# D3 clipping issues on zoom

Tags: d3.js, svg

I would like to use zoom behaviour in a simple d3 graph. The thing is that whenever I zoom in, the "main" group elements take up the whole svg space, which causes other existing elements such as axes and texts to get overlapped. I have read that clipping can be used to solve this problem but I didn't manage to get it working properly.

The following image (zoom in was applied) shows the problem:

[image: Clipping issues]

Related example with what I have tried so far can be found [here](http://blockbuilder.org/jarandaf/2e71a74c5a14ee9b6f3b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this problem. Key points were:

- Use proper svg element for clipping, normally `rect` does the job with corresponding width/height (same as your "drawing" area).
- Transform all elements drawn within the clip path (region), and not the parent group.

In code (omitting irrelevant parts), the result is:

```
// Scales, axis, etc.
...

// Zoom behaviour & event handler
let zoomed = function () {
  let e = d3.event;
  let tx = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.translate[0], width - width*e.scale));
  let ty = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.translate[1], height - height*e.scale));
  zoom.translate([tx,ty]);
  main.selectAll('.circle').attr('transform', 'translate(' + [tx,ty] + ')scale(' + e.scale + ')');
  svg.select('.x.axis').call(xAxis);
  svg.select('.y.axis').call(yAxis);
}  

let zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .x(x)
  .y(y)
  .scaleExtent([1,8])
  .on('zoom', zoomed);

const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
  .call(zoom);

const g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

// Set clip region, rect with same width/height as "drawing" area, where we will be able to zoom in
g.append('defs')
  .append('clipPath')
  .attr('id', 'clip')
  .append('rect')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

const main = g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'main')
  .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)');

let circles = main.selectAll('.circle').data(data).enter();
```

Comment: Good explanation! Had the same issue and this sorted it, thanks.